# Making fdisk see software RAID 0

Tags: livecd, ubuntu-10.10, raid-0, fdisk, grub2

I am following http://grub.enbug.org/Grub2LiveCdInstallGuide and I am using software RAID 0. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 LiveCD and is trying to restore grub2 after installing Windows 7 in another partition.

Here is the console's outputs:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Unable to seek on /dev/sad

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmraid -r
/dev/sdb: nvidia, "nvidia_acajefec", stripe, ok, 488397166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sda: nvidia, "nvidia_acajefec", stripe, ok, 488397166 sectors, data@ 0

So do you have an idea for how to make fdisk see my RAID array? How to make fdisk detect the Software RAID like dmraid?

Answer (score 1):

fdisk doesn't see RAID containers, fdisk sees partitions. Perhaps you meant to use fdisk on one of the device mapper devices instead.

Comment: Is that so? I don't know the ways around in Linux at all, so how can I tell fdisk to do what you've said instead?

Comment: Point it to one of the `/dev/dm-*` device nodes instead. Or maybe `/dev/md*`. I don't do much work with software RAID.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no such function in fdisk.